# how to fix a linting no shadowed variable wanring

Tags: javascript, typescript

In this function below I am getting a `no shadowed variable` warning on line two at `.reduce((nestedObject, key)`. How can I resolve this?

```
function deepAccessUsingString(obj, key) {
    return key.split('.').reduce((nestedObject, key) => {
        if (nestedObject && key in nestedObject) {
            return nestedObject[key];
        }
        return undefined;
    }, obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `key` being used in outer and inner function. You can simply give one of the `key` a different name.

```
function deepAccessUsingString(obj, key) {
    return key.split('.').reduce((nestedObject, key2) => {
        if (nestedObject && key2 in nestedObject) {
            return nestedObject[key2];
        }
        return undefined;
    }, obj);
}
```

Comment: np please select best answer :)